# Get income call event via Bluetooth

Tags: web-bluetooth

I have a phone and a simple site providing a list of numbers and names.

Is it possible to pair my phone with browsers via Bluetooth and pass an incoming number to the site in order to show the name of the caller? If the number isn't listed you have to fill it. So, I want to type using the Desktop browser and receive a call using a phone.

I'm using a web platform to store my client base. I tend to keep it on the web without coding Desktop API.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when you have something like a Bluetooth headset, the headset is a peripheral.

```
                    central -> peripheral
                  -----------------------
headset model     | phone   -> headset
desktop model (A) | phone   -> browser
desktop model (B) | browser -> phone
```

(**A**) is currently impossible with Web Bluetooth because, as of now, Web Bluetooth only supports using the web browser as a central, not a peripheral.

(**B**) may be possible, but it really depends on the mobile OS.  You would have to introduce special app to replace or augment the phone app on the mobile device so that it would act as a peripheral.

Comment: What if put B in the loop, won't it return a number? Coding a mobile app is the only way to make it happen, right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "put B in the loop", but yes, coding a mobile app is the only way to make (B) work.

Comment: I considered the browser-driven way. But the mobile one is okay as well. Thanks.